# How to limit comments through youtube data api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im looking for method of **Youtube data Api V3** in: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

I want to prohibit comments on my youtube videos.  But It seems to be no method like that. is there any way how to limit video comments?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like disabling comments from YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work right. now and they removed the feature. There is a bug reported on it over [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6194).

Comment: Please click the Star on the this page to indicate your desire for this feature. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=473

Comment: It looks like the Google developers have migrated the issues list to Github.com.Subscribe to updates about this issue here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/473#thread-subscription-status